# 500 internal server error when flask form contains null values

Tags: python, flask

I've got this form I'm posting to an app route called submitRegistration, code below...but rather then it returning back some json about the missing field, it's throwing a 500 internal server error. Can anyone comment why?

```
@app.route('/submitRegistration',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submitRegistration():
    try:
    _contactName = request.form['contact_name']
    _businessName = request.form['business_name']
    _telephone = request.form['telephone']
    _email = request.form['email']
    _address = request.form['address']
    _city = request.form['city']
    _state = request.form['state']
    _zip = request.form['zip']
    _services = request.form['services']

    # validate the received values
    if _contactName and _email and _telephone and _address and _city and _state and _zip and _services:

        # All Good, let's call MySQL
        conn = mysql.connect()
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.callproc('sp_submitRegistration',(_contactName,_businessName,_telephone,_email,_address,_city,_state,_zip,_services))
        data = cursor.fetchall()

        # SMS Confirmation
        smsClient = TwilioRestClient(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
        message = smsClient.messages.create(
            body=TWILIO_REG_SMS_MESSAGE,
            to=_telephone,
            from_=TWILIO_FROM_TELEPHONE,
        )

        if len(data) is 0:
            conn.commit()
            return json.dumps({'message':'Registration submitted successfully !'})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
    else:
        return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

except Exception as e:
    return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
finally:
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

***console output***

```
WARNING:tornado.access:404 GET /favicon.ico (2620:10d:c091:200::f:c1ec) 24.98ms
ERROR:__main__:Exception on /submitRegistration [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "app.py", line 113, in submitRegistration
    cursor.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment
ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /submitRegistration (<IPV6 ADDRESS>) 17.90ms
```

new app route...

```
# Functions 
@app.route('/submitRegistration',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submitRegistration():
    try:
    _contactName = request.form['contact_name']
    _businessName = request.form['business_name']
    _telephone = request.form['telephone']
    _email = request.form['email']
    _address = request.form['address']
    _city = request.form['city']
    _state = request.form['state']
    _zip = request.form['zip']
    _services = request.form['services']

    # validate the received values
    if _contactName and _email and _telephone and _address and _city and _state and _zip and _services != "":

            # All Good, let's call MySQL
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('sp_submitRegistration',(_contactName,_businessName,_telephone,_email,_address,_city,_state,_zip,_services)    )
            data = cursor.fetchall()

        # SMS Confirmation
        smsClient = TwilioRestClient(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
        message = smsClient.messages.create(
            body=TWILIO_REG_SMS_MESSAGE,  
            to=_telephone,
            from_=TWILIO_FROM_TELEPHONE,
            )       

        if len(data) is 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message': 'Registration submitted successfully !'})
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
        else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html': '<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
```

Comment: You are going to post the returned JSON?

Comment: What exception is shown on the server console?

Comment: Apart from understanding first the Exception, I would add a decorator to perform validation in the POST form.

Comment: Also changed over to tornado and starting happening, but same result with the built in dev server. And the form submission works fine when all fields are populated that are required, so not sure what I've done to break it...

Answer (score 0):

Answered here basically closing the mysql connection outside of the if statement created an out of scope condition...

Correction app.route below.

```
# Functions 
@app.route('/submitRegistration',methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submitRegistration():
    try:
    _contactName = request.form['contact_name']
    _businessName = request.form['business_name']
    _telephone = request.form['telephone']
    _email = request.form['email']
    _address = request.form['address']
    _city = request.form['city']
    _state = request.form['state']
    _zip = request.form['zip']
    _services = request.form['services']

    # validate the received values
    if _contactName and _email and _telephone and _address and _city and _state and _zip and _services != "":

            # All Good, let's call MySQL
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.callproc('sp_submitRegistration',(_contactName,_businessName,_telephone,_email,_address,_city,_state,_zip,_services)    )
            data = cursor.fetchall()

        # SMS Confirmation
        smsClient = TwilioRestClient(TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN)
        message = smsClient.messages.create(
            body=TWILIO_REG_SMS_MESSAGE,  
            to=_telephone,
            from_=TWILIO_FROM_TELEPHONE,
            )       

        if len(data) is 0:
                conn.commit()
                return json.dumps({'message': 'Registration submitted successfully !'})
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
        else:
                return json.dumps({'error':str(data[0])})
        else:
            return json.dumps({'html': '<span>Enter the required fields</span>'})

    except Exception as e:
        return json.dumps({'error':str(e)})
```